# id=ad6 showing strange results in Google Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome

I am writing a user form.  One of the fields is answer data.  I have given this an ID of ad1.  I have 50 boxes that come up and the strangest thing happens when I get ID6, 11, 31, and 32  They force the display to none and then show an ad.  This does not occur on firefox only Chrome.  I have scanned my machine for viruses and checked all my Chrome Extensions.  I do use Adblock plus.

I am currently using xampp.

My question is: Does Google Chrome have ads that can be displayed by using `id="ad6"` or `id="ad11"`?

My php code is below.

```
$x = 0;
for($x = 1; $x < 51; $x++){
    echo '<p id="ad' . $x . '">' . $x . "</p>";
}
```

Again the first element to "not show" will be `ad6`.
Also to make sure my computer wasnt infected with some kind of extension I checked the same thing on another computer running xampp and I get the same results.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Definitely geeking out about this.  I tried changing the id to ad-1 to ad-50  and that gives me 5 ads in 1 to 5.   If I go to any webpage and then change the ID using inspect element it will again show the ad.  Fascinating.

Comment: Thanks for the touch ups Wtower.  I'm new here.  I will work on formatting for future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of research the culprit is Adblock plus.  When this extension is enabled ADs can appear on your page created with PHP when you use certain IDs.
There are 2 solutions to the problem.

1. Disable Adblock plus for localhost pages.
2. Use different IDs in your code.

Thanks for all that viewed the question.